# document looks cut after using itextsharp.text.pdf to merge several itextsharp.text.pdf.PdfReader objects

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am using iTextSharp to create a `List<PdfReader> _documents` with several PDF documents.
After using merge on this list to create single paged document and send it to the client I see that the PDF looks cut in Adobe Reader.
When I highlight the picture like this I can see it's there  :

[image]

and if I save it it will be complete.

If I save one of `PdfReader` in list as single PDF document - without merge - it looks good.

[image]

The merge function is :

```
public void Merge(Stream outputStream)
{
    Document newDocument = null;

    try
    {
        newDocument = new Document();
        // Set margins and page size for the document 
        newDocument.SetMargins(50, 50, 50, 50);
        // There are a huge number of possible page sizes, including such sizes as 
        // EXECUTIVE, LEGAL, LETTER_LANDSCAPE, and NOTE 
        newDocument.SetPageSize(PageSize.A3 );

        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(newDocument, outputStream);

        newDocument.Open();
        PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

        if (EnablePagination)
        {
            _documents.ForEach(delegate(PdfReader doc)
            {
                _totalPages += doc.NumberOfPages;
            });
        }

        int currentPage = 1;
        foreach (PdfReader pdfReader in _documents)
        {
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                newDocument.NewPage();
                PdfImportedPage importedPage = pdfWriter.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, page);
                pdfContentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);

                if (EnablePagination)
                {
                    pdfContentByte.BeginText();
                    pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize(_baseFont, 9);
                    pdfContentByte.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER,
                        string.Format("{0} of {1}", currentPage++, _totalPages), 520, 5, 0);
                    pdfContentByte.EndText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        outputStream.Flush();
        if (newDocument != null)
            newDocument.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
    }
}
```

I suspect it has something to do with `newDocument.SetPageSize(PageSize.A3);`
but I am not sure and so far I can't find the solution.

Comment: The PDF file in the first image looks like being in portrait while the second one seems to be in landscape. Could it be a matter of rotation?

Comment: See my post here for dealing with page rotation http://stackoverflow.com/a/8229227/231316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of ideas to try. The problem could be related to scaling or sizing. Compare the Horizontal scaling of both documents. Also, the importedPage.PdfDocument.PageSize needs to be compared to the pdfContentByte.PdfDocument.PageSize, and probably scaled down.