# Issue while opening PDF file using httphandler

Tags: asp.net, pdf, httphandler

I am trying to generate a pdf file using httphandler. I have to call the httphandler from a button click event and I want the control to come back to the click event after calling the handler. The code is only able to open the pdf with Response.Redirect("HandlerURL"). Please let me know how can I open the file from the handler and want the control back to my page code. Using itextsharp for pdf creation.

Comment: See my [partially related answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17193199/231316). In HTTP (currently) you get one and only one response to a request. You can either send the PDF or you can send the HTML, but you can't do both. If you have this requirement, you will need to find a way to make a second request. One old school way is to generate the PDF and store it "somewhere" and return a "click here to download it". Ugly but it works. If you want to get fancy you can do some JavaScript work.

Comment: hey Chris, thanks for the reply. Actually I don't want any response back from the handler. Just want the handler to open the PDF and the code is there in the handler for that. And once the handler code executed want to execute the code written after calling handler in the parent page.

Comment: I guess I don't know exactly what you mean by "open" then. You have a button click, then on the server-side you want to create/manipulate a PDF and then have the button click continue to perform whatever ASP.Net normally does?